# Django database query to select all values in a column

Tags: django, database

Basicly I just want to say "give me all the values from column Y" and not "select all values and filter for Y based on primary key Z"

The word "column" is only mentioned one time on the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) page and the "primary key" and "row" options are very clearly explained in my eyes.

Now I wonder, how do I do this? :)

Comment: [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to query values for only a column, I think this is what you need:

```
MyModel.objects.values('column_name')
```

Or if you want to get a list of values:

```
MyModel.objects.values_list('column_name', flat=True)
```

You can apply any filter before selecting values:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(**criteria**).values_list('column_name', flat=True)
```